# How to put text above or below with checkbox?

Tags: android

How to put text above or below with checkbox ? Is that possible with checkBox in android ?

Comment: How about a CheckBox with no text, then a TextView that you place wherever you like?

Answer (score 2):

try to use `Layout`, even `LinearLayout` add your `Checkbox` to the `Layout` and add `TextView` up or down to the `Checkbox`

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I did for my project :

```
    LinearLayout llsomething = new LinearLayout(this);
    Checkbox cbSomething = new CheckBox(this);

    TextView tvSomething = new TextView(this);
    tvSomething.setText(R.string.something);

    llsomething.addView(cbSomething);
    llsomething.addView(tvSomething);
```

**EDIT :**

You can also make your layout clickable to do more "natural" :

```
llSomething.setClickable(true);
llSomething.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
              LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) v;
              CheckBox check = (CheckBox) layout.getChildAt(0);
              if(check.isChecked())
                  check.setChecked(false);
              else
                  check.setChecked(true);
        }
}
```

Comment: Add some explanation to the answer, please.

Comment: I just tricked. I used a vertical layout and i put a textless checkbox as the first child, then I added a textview with the text I wanted.